# Почему элемент hr меняет высоту?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title> Bisness template </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
 * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Arial', serif;
 font-size: 1em;
}
 button {
 padding: 10px 15px;
   width: 150px;
 background-color: rgb(231, 173, 72); 
  border: none;
  color: white;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
 .prices {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: rgb(231, 237, 243);
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.prices > h3 {
 align-self: center;
 text-align: center;
 color: rgb(57, 75, 80);
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
.prices > p {
 align-self: center;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 2px;
 color: rgb(117, 136, 141);
}
.prices .list {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 padding-top: 70px; 
}
.prices .el {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 450px;
 width: 380px;
 background-color: white;
 color: rgb(180, 186, 192);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid rgb(203, 213, 223);
}
.prices .main-el {
 height: 500px;
 background-color: rgb(112, 157, 202);
 position: relative;
 color: rgb(194, 225, 225);
 top: -25px;
 border: none;
}
.prices .element-content {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 80%;
}
.prices .el .element-content > h4 {
 color: rgb(129, 139, 149);
 font-size: 28px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.prices .el .element-content > h4 + p {
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
.prices .el  .element-content > p {
 padding-top: 12px;
 padding-bottom: 12px;
 text-align: center;
}
.prices .el .pr {
 color: rgb(255, 187,66);
 font-size: 54px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
.prices .el .element-content .pr  > sup {
 font-size: 32px;
}
.prices .el .element-content .pr + p {
 padding-top:  0;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.prices .el .element-content > button {
 align-self: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: rgb(255, 187,66);
}
.prices .el .element-content > hr {
 border: none;
 color: rgb(226, 233, 240);
 background-color: rgb(226, 233, 240);
 height: 2px;
}
.prices .main-el .element-content .pr {
 color: white;
}
.prices .main-el .element-content > h4 {
 color: white;
}
.prices .main-el  .element-content > hr {
 background-color: rgb(194, 225, 225);
}
</style>
 </head>
<body>
<section class="prices">
 <h3> Choose your price </h3>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameor m dolor sit am s itor si.</p>
 <div class="list">
 <div class="el">
  <div class="element-content">
  <h4>Basic plan</h4>
  <p class="pr"><sup>$</sup>22 </p> 
  <p> per month</p>
     <hr>
  <p>1 account</p>
  <hr>
  <p>8 hours support</p>
  <hr>
  <p>custom cloud services</p>
  <button> Get started </button>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="el main-el">
  <div class="element-content">
  <h4>Premium plan</h4>
  <p class="pr"><sup>$</sup>42 </p> 
  <p> per month</p>
  <hr>
  <p>1 account</p>
  <hr>
  <p>8 hours support</p>
  <hr>
  <p>custom cloud services</p>
  <button> Get started </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="el">
  <div class="element-content">
  <h4>Gold plan</h4>
  <p class="pr"><sup>$</sup>62 </p> 
  <p> per month</p>
  <hr>
  <p>1 account</p>
  <hr>
  <p>8 hours support</p>
  <hr>
  <p>custom cloud services</p>
  <button> Get started </button>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться в чем ошибка, я написала код для блока цен и добавила туда hr элементы, но они почему-то отображаются разной высоты, а когда я меняю размер экрана, они тоже меняют свою высоту, не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Не видно, что `hr` что-то меняет. Вот, что при смене разрешения происходит перенос заголовков не во всех блоках, это видно.